# Help identify Integrated Circuit

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I can't find information for the IC in the picture. It's a socketed 8 pin DIP that is part of the controller of a CNC machine. As far as I can see it receives signals from a microcontroller and then connects to a pair of 75176B which in turn connect to a Delta ASDA B2 servocontroller.
Thanks in advance.
[image: unknown IC]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UR mark suggests a safety-related part, such as an optocoupler.

And in fact, the Broadcom (formerly Avago, Agilent, or HP) HCPL-2630 has this marking:

[image]

It is a dual optocoupler. Full details [here](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optocouplers/industrial-plastic/digital-optocouplers/10mbd/hcpl-2630).

Comment: Proven correct, I don't know why it escaped my too many searches.